# transform: rotate(90deg) не поворачивает ширину блока

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой надо повернуть блок вертикально, когда поворачиваю этот блок, то его ширина не поворачивается и занимает всю область так как он был бы по горизонтали. Прикрепил картинку, чтоб было понятней. Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь!

```
transform-origin: center;
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WavWyQ)

Comment: А код добавить? Кто ж знает, что вы там понаписывали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повернул текст вертикально с помощью свойств:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: mixed;
```